# This if statement is very strange it only executes the if even given the parameters for the elif

Tags: if-statement, controls, structure

ok guys I wrote this script and the logic seems fine also syntax but when i try to execute this script itll ONLY execute the if not the else or elif??? I'm so confused please help me??? please try it and see what I mean???

```
import math

def main():

    usr = input('''Please select which task you would like to do?:
    plese TYPE either "Sphere Area" or "Sphere Volume"''')

    if (usr == "Sphere Area" or "sphere area"):
        sphereArea()   
    elif (usr == "Sphere Volume" or "sphere volume"):
        sphereVolume()           
    else:
        print("Please try again wrong choices:")
        return main()

def sphereArea():

    r = eval(input("Please input the radius: "))
    sa = float(4 * 3.14 *(r)**3)
    print(sa)

def sphereVolume():

    a,b,c = eval(input("Please input the Values for A,B,C in the order, please include comas::"))
    sv = float(4/3 * 3.14 * a*b*c)
    print("The Volume of the sphere is :",sv,"m3")


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always evaluates to true because: You have `usr == "Sphere Area" or "sphere area"`

In this, `"sphere area"` will always be true.

You should write: `usr == "Sphere Area" or usr == "sphere area"`